# C# PLINQ AsParallel().ForAll with Database call inside Loop

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, etl

I have written a logic using PLinq Asparallel.ForAll() I want to know the pit fall if any?

Also Please let me know how I can convert this logic using Task.StartNew((). will using Task be a better option?

Logic overview:
Here I have large data(200,000 rows minium) which I need to group and loop each record, check some condition , access database and finally need to update the EF Database based on certain logic.

```
 //Step1 
       var inputlst = DBMethed(); // Call to Database
    //Step 2 group inputlst
       var ginputLst = from p in inputlst
    group p by new 
    {
       p.ItemCode
    } into pg
    select new
    {
       ItemCode = pg.Key.ItemCode,
       ItemLst = pg.ToList()
    }

    ginputLst.Asparallel().ForAll(gItem =>
    {
         var itemDetails = GetItemDetails(ItemLst.ToList()) //DatabaseCall passing ItemCode List

         gItem.ItemLst.AsParallel().ForAll(x=>
         {
            var item = itemDetaisl.SingleOrDefault(y=> y.ItemCode = x.ItemCode)
            If(Item != null)
            {
                  IsExistItem = true;
                  StatusId = SomeLogic
            }
         });

          SomemoreLogic()
          DatabaseUpdate(gItem.ItemLst); // I am using EF to update Changed Items.
     });
```

Since I do lot of I/O operation compared to CPU intense work Is this right approach?

Comment: That's not "large data". That's average to small. Data marts typically have millions of rows. Data warehouses have TBs of data. Fix you SQL statement instead of trying to use client-side parallelism. ORMs are completely unsuitable for such tasks. The database server can actually finish processing in the time it takes for 200K rows to reach the client. Write a proper query, ensure you have the appropriate indexes. Make sure you have a good schema for reporting

Comment: What is the actual query you want to run? Which database are you using? What is the table schema? Indexes? Execution plan? Apart from EF being inappropriate, this question has nothing to do with it

Comment: I dont have problem with my Database query. I have to change the field value based on multiple conditions. Since I will be getting this in batches I thought to use Plinq Data parallelism where the records are processed parallely.

Comment: You have an ETL problem, but instead of solving it in the database, you try to pull all your data on the *client*, modify them then send them back. No amount of parallelism can fix that. What are you trying to do? Why not write an `UPDATE ... WHERE` statement? Or use ETL tools like SSIS? Why do you think that pulling 200K rows across the network is going to be faster than processing in the database itself, using its *far* more powerful processors and faster memory?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to update all `ItemLst` rows that have the same `ItemCode` key as the rows pulled from `DBMethed()` whatever that is. That's a simple join in the `FROM` clause of `UPDATE`.

Comment: There is huge,complex  business logic which is hidden in each stage.. That's why we didn't take the route of SSIS.

Comment: What ever example I gave is not the full logic.. I have just written a structure and highlighted my usage of AsParallel

Comment: Precisely for this reason you should have used the appropriate tools and/or architecture. Sorry, you can't cover up this mistake on the client side. At best you are trying to use the equivalent of client-side cursors, the slowest way to process data possible.

Comment: An appropriate solution would be to use TPL Dataflow and create a pipeline of blocks that process individual records and pass them to the next step, finally storing them in the databse. That's what SSIS Dataflows do by the way. Use a microORM like Dapper to pull the data from the source or even raw ADO.NET - EF offers nothing here. Caching all the data in memory also doesn't offer anything, unless it's small lookup data

Comment: The queries should retrieve all the appropriate data too, instead of executing yet another query to lazily load related items. The difference is between one modest query vs 200K useless roundtrips. Maybe your code won't end up 200K times slower, but it will be close

Comment: All that from the guy that processes some million airline tickets and credit card transactions monthly. Some hints: compression reduces IO, the main cause for delays. SQL Server's Change Tracking (not CDC) means that I *don't* have to process all of the rows, just the modified ones. Instead of hours, I process the changes in 10 minutes. And it's available even in SQL Server Express. Columnstores are nice too, and they come in all versions of SQL Server 2016 SP1, even Express.

Comment: Finally, Hand-coded dataflows are used to process and import text files with weird formats into a staging database, something that is difficult to do with SSIS. The rest of the work is done with SSIS and SQL statements though.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos  Thanks for your input.. I will look into TPL DataFlow as suggested..